# When i pass null value in search parameter it display no record mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am passing blank('') value in search parameter, it display no record. I want, when i pass null or blank value it ignore that parameter from search query, and display record. My code is

```
var _branchName = req.query.branchName;
var _personName = req.query.personName;
var _clientID = req.query.clientID;

var _searchQRY = [
    {
        branchName: { $regex: _branchName, $options: '-i' }
    },
    {
        personName: { $regex: _personName, $options: '-i' }
    },
    {
        "client._id": _clientID
    },
    {
        isDeleted: { $ne: true }
    }];

objModel.find({ $and: _searchQRY }, function (err, results) {
    res.json({ status: config.responseStatus, record: results })
});
```

In this i pass "_clientID" is blank(''). At that time i want to ignore that parameter and search on remains parameter.

Comment: So what is your expectation when you pass blank `_clientId` ?

Comment: @dikesh when i pass it blank, it fetch only null _clientId. but i want all record. Means, i want to ignore _clientID search on search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do smth like

```
var _branchName = req.query.branchName;
var _personName = req.query.personName;
var _clientID = req.query.clientID;

var _searchQRY = [
    {
        branchName: { $regex: _branchName, $options: '-i' }
    },
    {
        personName: { $regex: _personName, $options: '-i' }
    },
    {
        isDeleted: { $ne: true }
    }];

if (_clientID) {
    _searchQRY.push(
        {
            "client._id": _clientID
        }
    );
}

objModel.find({ $and: _searchQRY }, function (err, results) {
    res.json({ status: config.responseStatus, record: results })
});
```

I.e. include `client._id` in the search query only when you do specify it in the request.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, when `_clientID` is blank, change its value to object like this

```
if (_clientID == '')
    _clientID = { $exists : true};
```

This will match all the `client._id` when _clientID is empty string `''`